# Using Alt+Drag to make a rectangular selection loses editor focus

Tags: windows, windows-7, phpstorm

If I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Drag</kbd> to make a rectangular selection in PhpStorm, the program moves focus to the menu bar (like when you press just <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Windows apps). I then need to do click <kbd>Esc</kbd> to restore focus, thus making the short-cut rather pointless.

I've tried checking the **Disable mnemonics in menu** option at **File → Settings → IDE Settings → Window Options** but it only hides the underline character in menu items.

Is there a decent way to make rectangular selections with the mouse?

Comment: What PhpStorm version do you have there? Seems to be working just fine for me on home and work PCs (v8 EAP; Win 7 x64 SP1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, please see [IDEA-87408](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87408)

Comment: That's right. If you go to "File → Settings → IDE Settings → Appearance → Theme" and you switch away from "Windows" theme, it gets fixed.